# how to programmatically close android background suspended running process???(not terminating only closing)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I just want to know the sourcecode for closing background process in android(not terminating).
Any body suggest me how to programmatically close the background suspended running process in android(not terminating)?
Also suggest me any github source codes are available for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Closing means just to quit all background suspended running apps behind screen......
(Instead of dragging the apps to quit,I want to know how to programmatically quit(not force stop) in task manager.just want to quit  the apps from ram.